# Python code error in making an age guessing program

Tags: python

I am making an age guessing program which take 3 inputs. 1st Input: number between 1 to 10. 2nd Input: Year of Birth. 3rd Input: True or False. What is the problem in my python program? Tell How I can take boolean input from my user?

```
x = input("Enter your selected number")

y = input("Year of Birth")

z = input()

if z = True:
    print (100 * int(x)) + 2019 - int(y)
elif:
    print (100 * int(x)) + 2018 - int(y)
```

Comment: try asking the user for `yes/no` and then comparing the input with `yes` or `no` to check if the input should be `True` or `False` - there is no direct way to take boolean input from the user.

Comment: also use comparison operator == instead of assignment operator = in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here most likely is because of the operator '=' which is used for attributing not to test the equality between variables.

You need to use '==' for example:

```
if z == True:
...
```

Also, as a notice to what @rdas mentioned even if you take input from the user in variable z, the input will still be string. Take in consideration that even if you will input 'False' from the keyboard that will still be treated as True in boolean.

```
bool('True') ==> True
bool('False') ==> True
```

So instead of checking True/False you should test the input on a string keyword, for example "yes/no"